# Overlapping a part of a div css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have this kind of problem. The black div which I marked with red border is part of a  bigger div as you can see in the screenshot. My problem is that I want only the black div to overlap over the orange one...So that the white area that is on the screenshot to miss. I will be really glad if someone could help me

Here is the image : [https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/11136877_827684263972895_353490705_n.jpg?oh=4545d61c50bc45f2e6ea518e62eb7f76&oe=55212ADF&**gda**=1428248450_df17013e8177c387e39680e8ec6e9639](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/11136877_827684263972895_353490705_n.jpg?oh=4545d61c50bc45f2e6ea518e62eb7f76&oe=55212ADF&__gda__=1428248450_df17013e8177c387e39680e8ec6e9639)

Comment: Please post relevant HTML and CSS here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can add negative margin to black div.

```
.blackdiv {
   margin-buttom: -20px;
}
```